# Retrieve a deleted database in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, restore

I accidently deleted the whole database when I should just delete one table in PHPMyAdmin. Is there a way of retrieving the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Have a working backup of the system, and restore the files from it.
- An undelete tool might help, if you deleted the db *very* recently (and ideally, if you unplugged the computer right afterward).

As for doing it with MySQL, though...on all systems i'm aware of, no.  MySQL tables are files in the server's data directory, and dropping a table deletes those files.  Once they're gone, they're gone, and only the methods above can get them back.  A database is a directory of those files, and dropping it deletes the whole directory.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened with me, found a easy solution. First make a command line access to the database using the `mysql.exe` file present in `xampp/php/bin` folder. Delete the `phpmyadmin` database. Then, just import the `create_tables.sql` file to the `phpmyadmin database`. This solved my problem.

Let me know if you face any problem using this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here :-(
I closed xampp (V3.2.1) found the xampp\mysql\ folder, right-clicked and selected Restore previous version, select recent restore. When this finished I opened xampp and the missing database was back with the information dated as per the restore date. Not ideal but better than no database :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a accidentally deleted database via a file restoration software. Check this free software

http://www.majorgeeks.com/Restoration_d4474.html

More information here - 
http://emaillenin.blogspot.com/2010/11/recover-accidentally-deleted-mysql.html